# Assign initial value to \pgfmathaccuma

Tags: pgfplotstable, pgfmath

I cannot assign zero initially to `\pgfmathaccuma` and `\pgfmathaccumb`. It gives this error:

`! Missing number, treated as zero.`

Then I press `s` to skip. However, `\pgfmathaccumb` is always empty! I want to set its initial value to zero.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
index   mmtype
0       0
1       0
2       0
3       1
4       0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{data.txt}\origtable

\pgfplotstablenew[]{6}\newtable

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
create col/assign/.code={\pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\pgfplotstablerow},
]{rowid}\newtable

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
create col/assign/.code={%
\ifx\pgfmathaccuma\pgfutil@empty
\pgfmathparse{0}%
\let\pgfmathaccuma=\pgfmathresult
\fi
\ifx\pgfmathaccumb\pgfutil@empty
\pgfmathparse{0}%
\let\pgfmathaccumb=\pgfmathresult
\fi
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\orgrow{\pgfplotstablerow-\pgfmathaccuma}%
b:\pgfmathaccumb|
\ifx\pgfmathaccumb=0
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\orgrow}{mmtype}\of\origtable%
    \ifx\pgfplotsretval=1
        01
        \pgfmathparse{\pgfmathaccuma+1}%
        \let\pgfmathaccuma=\pgfmathresult%
        \pgfmathparse{1}%
        \let\pgfmathaccumb=\pgfmathresult%
    \fi
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\orgrow%
\else
    \orgrow:1
    \pgfmathparse{0}%
    \let\pgfmathaccumb=\pgfmathresult%  
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\orgrow%
\fi
},]{mmtypenewrow}\newtable

\pgfplotstabletypeset\newtable

\end{document}
```

My aim is to repeat `index` if its `mmtype` is equal to 1. For example, when input data is as follow:

```
index   mmtype
0       0
1       0
2       0
3       1
4       0
```

output data must be:

```
mmtypenewrow    mmtype
0               0
1               0
2               0
3               1
3               1
4               0
```

Comment: After changing `\ifx` to `\ifnum`, code does what I want. @egreg's solution must be added also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `\pgfutil@empty` where you can't: in the document the character `@` can't be normally used for making control sequences with, so the result is that `\ifx` compares `\pgfmathaccuma` with `\pgfutil` (which is undefined) and the test is false.

How to skip this problem? Either you surround your code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` or define differently the test:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
index   mmtype
0       0
1       0
2       0
3       1
4       0
\end{filecontents}

%%% Define a macro for testing against `\pgfutil@empty`    
\makeatletter
\def\checkforempty#1{TT\fi\ifx#1\pgfutil@empty}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{data.txt}\origtable

\pgfplotstablenew[]{6}\newtable

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
create col/assign/.code={\pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\pgfplotstablerow},
]{rowid}\newtable

\makeatletter
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
create col/assign/.code={%
\if\checkforempty\pgfmathaccuma
  \pgfmathparse{0}%
  \let\pgfmathaccuma=\pgfmathresult
\fi
\ifx\checkforempty\pgfmathaccumb
  \pgfmathparse{0}%
  \let\pgfmathaccumb=\pgfmathresult
\fi
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\orgrow{\pgfplotstablerow-\pgfmathaccuma}%
b:\pgfmathaccumb|
\ifx\pgfmathaccumb=0
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\orgrow}{mmtype}\of\origtable%
    \ifx\pgfplotsretval=1
        01
        \pgfmathparse{\pgfmathaccuma+1}%
        \let\pgfmathaccuma=\pgfmathresult%
    \fi
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\orgrow%
\else
    \orgrow:1
    \pgfmathparse{0}%
    \let\pgfmathaccumb=\pgfmathresult%  
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\orgrow%
\fi
},]{mmtypenewrow}\newtable

\pgfplotstabletypeset\newtable

\end{document}
```

So you can do

```
\if\checkforempty\pgfmathaccuma
```

and the code will do what you're looking for.